# distance between two parallel quadratic curves

Tags: trigonometry

Say I have a quadratic curve described by
$ x^{T}Ax + b^Tx + c =0 $.
Then I do some arbitrary translation to the curve to create a new curve. How to I calculate the distance between the pair of points on the two curves that correspond to each other before and after the translation?

Comment: What does mean parallelism between two quadratic curves? For example, for the hyperbola $yx=1$ and for the conic degenerate in product of two lines $(y-3x+1)(y-x+2)=0$

Comment: 'parallel' here simply means you can obtain one curve from another by doing some translation operation.

Comment: Apply the same translation to the origin $O$, to some point $O'$. The distance between any corresponding points will be $|OO'|$.

Comment: @Andrei the problem is, given $ x^{T}A_1x + b_1^Tx + c_1 =0 $ and $ x^{T}A_2x + b_2^Tx + c_2 =0 $, how do i know which two points on the two curves correspond to each other...

Comment: @Then it is not simply a new curve such that the distance from any point of the first curve to the other one IS CONSTANT (a definition of parallelism).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $b$ be some vectors of length $N$, and $A$ an $N\times N$ matrix. Let's write the original curve in terms of elements:
$$x^TAx+b^Tx+c=0\\\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{i,j}x_i x_j+\sum_{i=1}^N b_ix_i+c=0$$
Now let's translate the curve by a vector $\Delta=(\delta_1,...,\delta_N)$. You will need to replace $x_i$ by $x_i-\delta_i$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{i,j}(x_i-\delta_i) (x_j-\delta_j)+\sum_{i=1}^N b_i(x_i-\delta_i)+c=0$$
We now try to group together terms with $x_i x_j$ and terms with $x_i$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{i,j}x_i x_j+\sum_{i=1}^N \left[b_i-2a_{i,i}\delta_i-\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^N\left(a_{i,j}+a_{j,i}\right)\delta_j\right]x_i+\\\left[c+\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^Na_{i,j}\delta_i \delta_j-\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i\delta_i\right]=0$$
We can write this as $$x^TA'x+b'^Tx+c'=0$$
Note that your $A'$ must be equal to $A$. Then identifying elements of $b'$ with the corresponding terms in the shifted equation yields:
$$b'_i=b_i-2a_{i,i}\delta_i-\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}^N\left(a_{i,j}+a_{j,i}\right)\delta_j$$
This is a linear system of $N$ equations with $N$ unknowns ($\delta_i$). You can calculate all $\delta_i$ to get $\Delta$. You should also check if $c'$ and the last term in the shifted curve equation are the same. Otherwise you distort the curve (they are not parallel).

Comment: Can I check what is '$a_{j_i}$'?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I used `_` instead of `,`